# cast from ‘’ to ‘char’ loses precision [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

I don't know how to deal with this error.
I have a code:

```
typedef struct LOGIN
{
    mutable std::string name;
    mutable int heslo;

}TCP_LOGIN;

void rec_data(BYTE dats)
{
    LOGIN myPtr;

    char *pADdata = (char*)(&myPtr);

    Server->prijem_dat((char)(&pADdata));

}
```

And I have a mistake :

```
cast from ‘char**’ to ‘char’ loses precision [-fpermissive]
      Server->prijem_dat((char)(&pADdata))(&myPtr));
                                                 ^
```

This is c ++ (it's part of the recv (socket) function which is fine, it's just a matter of receiving the data structure and having them where to write it)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you're trying to do, those casts make no sense at all.

Comment: `typedef struct` looks like C, but those casts look like C++?

Comment: Are you trying to convert an address (more or less an "int") to a char? Or a whole struct to a char?

Comment: That cast doesn't make sense. Did you perhaps mean to cast to `char*` (and for that only `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myPtr)` would be enough)?

Comment: You are casting a `LOGIN*` pointer into a single `char`, so you will lose bytes in the value of the pointer, that is what the compiler is complaining about. You need to cast to another pointer type instead, in this case `char*`

Comment: Why `mutable`?  Almost certainly not needed.